# Imbalanced Classes in Convolutional Neural Networks

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, keras, convolution

I have a classification problem where the class of interest is only 7% of the dataset, and the entire population is roughly 1200 observations.

I understand that `ImageDataGenerator` from Keras helps with augmenting the data to increase the number of observations before training the model, however is it possible to augment only one class, as in add noise, blur or perform transformations only on the minority class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either try to balance with the class_weight argument in the fit() function that takes a dictionary mapping classes to a weight value. You could even use sklearn to calculate the proper class weights. See PScs answer here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras

Or you could use Keras ImageDateGenerator with flow_from_directory() and save an image augmenting run to a directory with the save_to_dir argument thereby generating more examples of the underrepresented class: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator

For that dummy run you only provide samples of the class that you want more samples of.

Then you use your balanced training and validation data for your actual training.

Answer (score 1):

There is a machine learning toolkit that allows you to perform augmenting on the images including Transformations, Zoom/Strech, Noise and blurring.

The Image Augmentor can be found here: 
https://github.com/codebox/image_augmentor